# Error when Running a function in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I successfully created the following function in mysql

```
CREATE FUNCTION h2m
HTMLText(text)
RETURNS text
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE Start INT;
DECLARE End INT;
DECLARE Length INT;
SET Start = CHARINDEX('<',HTMLText);
SET End = CHARINDEX('>',HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',HTMLText));
SET Length = (End - Start) + 1;
WHILE Start > 0
AND End > 0
AND Length > 0
DO
SET HTMLText = STUFF(HTMLText,Start,Length,'');
SET Start = CHARINDEX('<',HTMLText);
SET End = CHARINDEX('>',HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',HTMLText));
SET Length = (End - Start) + 1;
END WHILE;
RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(HTMLText));
END;
```

Now when I'm trying to call it with the following code:

```
SELECT description h2m (HTMLText) FROM oc_product_description,
```

I am getting the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use in '(HTML Text) FROM oc product_description LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2 –
```

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.  First the `CHARINDEX()` function isn't a built-in MySQL function.  Unless you have it custom defined somewhere in your DB, you'll run into an error here.  `LOCATE()` is the built-in MySQL function that does something similar to what `CHARINDEX()` does.

Your second problem is the way you're calling the function.  You should be calling it in this fashion

```
SELECT h2m (description) 
FROM oc_product_description
```

Comment: Everything you mentioned worked like a charm, Would you please give me a command to execute the function that I have stored? the command I have right now only selects them. This function is suppose to search description column and convert html codes to text by eliminating the html tags.

Comment: @Schwann I am not sure I understand your question.  The command you have right now is already searching and converting your HTML

Comment: @Liyod, I did use that command, but it did not update and change the column, it just selected and gave me a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
SELECT description, h2m(HTMLText)
FROM oc_product_description
```

Three things:

- Comma after `description`.
- Removing space between `h2m` and `(`.  MySQL has a problem with spaces after function names.
- Removal of comma after `oc_product_description`.

EDIT:

Perhaps you want to pass `description` in as the argument:

```
SELECT h2m(description)
FROM oc_product_description
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff, I ran yours and It gives me unknown column HTMLText error

Comment: Now it says,  Commands out of sync, you cannot run this command now!